# Did Gorbachev say that his intention was to destroy Communism?

Tags: 20th-century, soviet-union, communism

As I remember the 1980s and the Perestroika epoch, the reforms were advertised to the people as "return to Leninist principles", even deeper implementation of Socialism. The posters claimed it was "duty of every Communist to be in the vanguard of the perestroika".

Yet many Russian internet sites claim that when speaking abroad Gorbachev admitted that his aim was actually to combat Communism. For instance, often cited his undated speech in American university in Turkey with a [reference to Slovak newspaper "Usvit", No 24, 1999](http://www.sovross.ru/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=58241).

In the speech Gorbachev makes some notable confessions:

> The aim of the whole my life was the destruction of Communism (...) my wife understood the necessity of it even before me. For this goal I used my position in the party and in the country. That's why she emphatically pushed me to occupy higher and higher positions in the party and government (...) When I myself accustomed with the West, I understood that I cannot give up this aim. (...)

In the speech he admits that he created a conspiracy with A.Yakovlev and E. Shevardnadze in pursuit of this goal.

If the speech is true it would mean at least a dishonest betrayal of his voters who voted for the "return to Leninist ideals" as it was declared, not to say of his party who trusted him and put in the highest position.

Yet the speech very much resembles the confessions of the Stalinist show trials of the 1930s where some higher officials confessed in wreckage conspiracies and plotting to restore Capitalism.

So my question is whether the speech is authentic?

Comment: What kind of voters that would be possibly "dishonestly betrayed" do you mean, referring to USSR?

Comment: @Darek Wędrychowski those who supported Perestroika because it was advertised as "return to Leninist principles" and as a "left" change. Up to the mid-1990s nobody admitted that they want to restore Capitalism. Various euphemisms were introduced. If somebody admitted it in 1980s he would be very unpopular.

Comment: @Darek Wędrychowski I also remember other slogans from the epoch - that is "restoration of the workers' self-govenment" and "factories to the workers" (euphemisms for privatization), "all power to the Soviets" (a re-use of the Leninist slogan from 1917, now used as an euphemism for removal CPSU from the power). Market economy was advertised as a return to Leninist NEP which allegedly was stoped by Stalin against Lenin's will, etc.

Comment: By asking about the voters, I mean who did you have in mind. Because in order to have voters, there has to be some kind of elections. Gorbachev became General Secretary in 1985, by votes of politburo (or Central Committee, I'm not sure if I remember well), as previous favorite of Andropov. So you mean that they would be the "betrayed" ones, right? Also from what I know, the reforms of Perestroika were introduced later, in January 1987. Was that also the time when "return to Leninist ideals" was announced, or was the slogan advertised before the elections?

Comment: @Darek Wędrychowski I am speaking not only about Gorbachev himself, but about attitude to Perestroika in general. There were many politicians who advocated Perestroika and were thus supported by the voters. My impression is that the general attitude to Perestroika was positive till the early 1990s. It was supported among others by old party members who would not abandon ideas of Communism in any case. But they were disoriented by the state propaganda which was hiding the true nature of perestroika. And regarding Gorbachev, he became "president" after being elected by a new body "congress".

Comment: I've found it, the idea of reforms was first introduced in April 1985.

Comment: Of course Gorbie would tell the **westerners** who he wanted money and help from that he was against Socialism. It's called being a politician. You tell your audience what they want to hear and believe. That has no bearing on whether he was or wasn't.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think it's a decent question, asking for the veracity of a certain report.

Comment: This was cross-posted at Skeptics and Politics: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/15509/5 and http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/1188

Comment: @FelixGoldberg the question is leading in an incorrect direction, by postulating the assumption that Gorbie wanted to destroy communism, which was the last thing on his mind. He wanted a "return to true communism".

Comment: @jwenting it is asking, not postulating what you said.

Comment: @jwenting: I see what you mean. Frankly, this was my first thought too, when I read the title. But when I read the whole question I realized it was a good one. So, here's a suggestion to Anixx: replace "admit" with "say" in the title.

Comment: I changed from "ever admit", which presumes guilt, to the more neutral "say".

Comment: -1 for your free interpretation again. "In the speech he admits that he created a conspiracy with A.Yakovlev and E. Shevardnadze in pursuit of this goal." - No, he does not. There is no such thing in that text, it is your invention, just like in this question: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/982/what-is-the-truthfullness-of-the-film-revolution-com-usa-the-conquest-of-the

Comment: He was asked this question 3 times on russian TV and was highly evasive in his replies. At first he didn't deny anything, but made excuse that his opinion changed over time, just like Lenin changed his methods before and after the revolution. The second time he denied this claim and said it's propaganda of the communist party. Then he was asked by the host of the show again if he thinks that communism must be destroyed. He replied that we should fight for democracy and freedoms.
https://youtu.be/GDK9kAcQslE?t=1627

Comment: https://provereno.media/blog/2022/09/05/govoril-li-gorbachyov-chto-celyu-ego-zhizni-bylo-unichtozhenie-kommunizma/

Comment: Complete speech: https://www.revolutionarydemocracy.org/rdv6n1/gorbach.htm

Comment: Archived version of the publication mentioned in the question: https://archive.ph/7kjzF

Comment: Tweet about Gorbachev's visit in a university in Ankara: https://twitter.com/cerenkenar/status/1564725867858874369

Comment: Turkish university mentioned in the publications: Bilkent university https://w3.bilkent.edu.tr/bilkent/

Comment: Gorbachev's speech published by German newspaper "Die rote Fahne": https://sascha313.wordpress.com/2019/09/09/michail-basmanow-lew-trotzki-und-die-iv-internationale/

According to the article the Grobachev's speech at the university was published on youtube with the title "Mikhail Gorbachev speaks at Bilkent University (28.04.1995.)" but was removed later.

Comment: Turkish press about Gorbachev's visit in Ankara in 1995: https://onedio.com/haber/sscb-nin-dagilmasindan-sorumlu-tutulan-gorbacov-un-1995-te-gerceklestirdigi-olayli-odtu-ziyareti-839671

Comment: Turkish university visited by Gorbachov in Ankara in 1995 where students threw eggs at him(from Turkish tweets and Turkish press): https://www.metu.edu.tr/tr

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I see it, there are two different aspects here:

1. Is the speech itself authentic?
2. Are its contents true?

To answer 1 negatively, one could demonstrate, for example, that there is no American University in Turkey or that Gorbachev never visited Turkey in 1999.

To show why 2 is different from 1 even if 1 happens to be true, consider the option that Gorbachev, a consummate career politician, could have been describing in 1999 his own past thought and actions in terms and ways he thought his audience there and then would appreciate, not necessarily giving a true representation.

For now let me focus on 1, which is the easier question. This answer is not final yet so I'll be updating it as I find out more. For now:

- First of all, it's not clear that USVIT, the alleged source, exists. We are told that it's a Slovak newspaper. Immediately one wonders: why would a *Slovak* newspaper be reporting on this? And if the event were newsworthy enough to reach Slovakia, can mention of it be found in other sources?

The [Wikipedia list of Slovak papers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_newspapers_in_Slovakia) does not mention an *Usvit* but this is not conclusive at all, of course (wiki is not 100% reliable, the paper could have been closed or renamed since) but nevertheless it does give some pause.

Also, there is a [*Czech* political party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_of_Direct_Democracy) called Usvit - Czech, not Slovak.

On the balance, the Usvit source is really fishy.

So I googled it a bit in English and found a [translation of the alleged speech to English](http://www.revolutionarydemocracy.org/rdv6n1/gorbach.htm) - and there its credited to "the 'Dialog' newspaper in the Czech Republic".

To sum up, unless somebody finds an actual copy of N.24 of the Slovak Usvit newspaper, I tend to think that it never existed as such and makes the whole text quite suspect.

- Is there an American University in Turkey?

Once again, wikipedia has a [helpful list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_universities_in_Turkey) and according to it there is no such institution! We still cannot rule out closure or renaming since 1999 but it does seem likely that the whole thing is made up at this stage.

There is however, an [American University in Northern Cyprus](http://www.gau.edu.tr/en) which is a Turkish fief. But it does not seem to have a branch in Ankara or anything.

So, the venue seems to be made up as well.

- I am not qualified to perform a proper lexical or philological analysis of the alleged speech or even an ngram search (like we did [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/what-is-the-truth-behind-this-speech-by-lord-macaulay)), but one point sticks out as a sore thumb: the mention of Gorbachev's wife as the propelling power for his rise in the party. Is it a sensible thing for a politician to say in a speech? Does it make sense for him to say that his actions and his very ideas were actually his wife's?

If on the other hand, we recall that [Gorbachev's late wife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raisa_Gorbachova) is particularly reviled in certain communist/nationalist/antisemitic circles in Russia, then her inclusion makes sense: the forgers could not help including a shot at their favourite target, even at the expense of the whole thing's veracity.

**To sum up: the "speech" is with %99.9 probability fake.**

Comment: Two notes: 1. There is a Slovak political party also called Usvit, which also publishes a magazine called Usvit. If this existed in 1999 I don't know. In any case it's a communist-orthodox fringe party with no national representation so it wouldn't change the conclusion. 2. The English translation does in fact not match what Anixx is describing. This has happened with him in another question. The quotes does *not* indicate any "conspiracy" and does not mean a betrayal of anything Leninist.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Actually, the translation seems to be quite ok. I don't quite see why you think it doesn't match with the original. (Of course, the original itself is a bunch of crappy lies invented by Gorbie's enemies to smear him but that is not the point, is it?)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the Russian text matched what Anixx was saying. Just that the English text didn't. Google translate does indeed indicate that the Russian text also does not match Anixx claims.

Comment: Very poor research. Really bad answer.

Comment: @DieterPisarewski I am sorry you feel this way. Would you care to explain why you think my research there was poor? What is lacking in your opinion? Do you disagree with the conclusion?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Check the comments below the question

Answer (score 12):

I trust [David Remnick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Remnick)'s *Lenins's Tomb: The Last Days of the Soviet Empire* as a source, which includes this passage:

> To begin with, Gorbachev himself was still convinced of what he called
>   the "rightness of socialist choice." He continued to see Lenin as his
>   guiding intellectual and historical model. There is absolutely no
>   evidence to suggest that Gorbachev was out to undermine, much less
>   destroy, the basic tenets of ideology or statehood of the Soviet
>   Union. Certainly not in 1987.

It may be relevant that 1987 is closer in time to the main transformative events affecting Soviet Communism than is 1999. I personally don't think the quoted "admission" is authentic in an objective sense.

Answer (score 6):

There are several questions in here. I'll try to address each one:

**Q1: Did Gorbachev betray his voters who voted for a return to Leninist ideals?**

**No.** The reason he didn't do that is twofold.

1. He didn't have any voters. Gorbachev came to power in a totalitarian dictatorship. His assumption to power was completely undemocratic. Nobody hence voted for any return to Leninist ideals. (There was an [election in 1989](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Union_legislative_election,_1989), and this election served both to legitimize Gorbachev and take steps towards democracy, but it did not bring him to power, and the election would not have been able to bring him down from power either).
2. A "return to Leninist ideals" means primarily things like equality, and the people being in control. This means democracy, and this was what Gorbachev was working for. His aim was a socialist democracy. He believed in Marx and Lenin's ideals, but he had realized that the so called "dictatorship of the proletariat" was not the way forward. Hence he retained the *ideals*, but rejected the *methods*. Therefore it was not a betrayal of the ideals.

There therefore was no voters to betray, and he also did not betray his supporters or Leninist ideals. What he did was simply to fail. Instead of succeeding in his aim to bring democracy to the Soviet Union, his steps towards democracy instead led the Soviet Union to collapse. To his credit though, this has led to [democracy in Estonia, Lithuania and Latvia](http://www.wilsoncenter.org/publication/the-failure-democracy-post-soviet-eurasia), so his efforts wasn't a complete failure.

**Q2: Is the sources for the text reliable?**

**No.** Felix Goldberg in his answer explains well why it isn't reliable. In fact the claimed sources generally don't seem to exist. Also in one case it's claimed to be a speech, in another an interview, which casts further doubt on the text.

There is today a publication in Slovakia called "Usvit" but it's doubtful it existed in 1999, and if it did it's a one-man show by a local fringe politician. It seems highly unlikely that this guy had secured an interview with Gorbachev.

The text is variously claimed to be from the American University in Turkey. That University does not exist. There is an American University in Cyprus, though. However, the text is otherwise claimed to be from an interview in Ankara. The only reference I can find to Gorbachev and Ankara is from a 1997 publication in Turkish. The source is not reliable.

**Q3: Did Gorbachev say that his intention was to destroy Communism?**

**No.** I can't find any reliable sources on Gorbachev himself saying that he wanted to destroy communism. The text in this question seems to be the only case, and as we have seen, these texts are not reliable.

During the cold war, the word "communism" was generally associated with socialist dictatorships, while the word "socialism" was wider and included those who wanted both socialism and democracy. With that usage of the word it could therefore be claimed that he indeed wanted to destroy communism, as he wanted to make the USSR democratic. But he himself seems not to have made such a claim.

**Q4: Is the text authentic?**

**No.** Most of the things in the interview seem rather unremarkable. Gorbachev claims to want a social democracy, something he has said otherwise. He said even before the fall of USSR that he wanted a more open market. There is no mention of a conspiracy at all, that seems to be Anixx own invention.

In fact, the only remarkable statement is "The purpose of my life was the destruction of communism, unbearable dictatorship over the people". Nowhere else do we find Gorbachev claiming that he wanted to destroy communism.

We do however find him saying that he wanted democracy. As such this quote is probably an intentional distortion of what he said. He most likely said that he wanted to destroy the unbearable dictatorship over the people.

So whoever decided to wrote the original article was probably a dedicated anti-democratic communist, and decided to change the headline to something more controversial.  Therefore, at a minimum we can conclude that the article as a whole isn't reliable, and that the claim that he wanted to destroy communism probably is falsified.

As the sources seem to made up, and also Gorbachev's visit to Turkey seems made up, it's likely that the whole text is made up. But it's probably largely made up from things he actually have said in other interviews and in his 1995 autobiography. The claim that he wanted to destroy communism is however most likely completely invented.

Comment: My relatives voted for him and later regreted. By claiming he had no voters to betray, you offend those people.

Comment: @Anixx: No they did not vote for him. You probably misunderstand. They might have *supported* him and later regretted this, but they did not **vote** for him. They may also be referring to the 1989 election to the soviet congress (the only one where you ever had any choice). In that election they could not vote for Gorbachev, but they may have voted for the communist party, and later regretted it. But your relatives never ever voted for Gorbachev.

Comment: well I admit they actually just supported him, but felt betrayed. You should note that there were actually people who voted for him, both in the Congress and at his electoral district.

Comment: @Anixx Gorbachev was elected by the party, not by an electoral district, as I understand it. The members of congress who "voted" for Gorbachev as president has no one else to vote for he was the only candidate. That is not "voting" in any normal sense. It's time for you to realize that the USSR was not a democracy.

It's good to see you admit that your relatives didn't vote for him. It would be better if you stopped using words as if they are mere decoration. Words have meaning, and if they didn't vote for him in a free election, then calling them voters is dishonest.

Comment: The election may well have had ballots listing his name as first candidate for the party or some such wording. Same happens in other countries. You mark the name of a candidate but the vote goes to the party (with some hybrid systems giving votes to candidates until they have enough votes to gain a seat in the assembly, then all others going to the party as a whole).

Comment: @jwenting I think the 1989 elections were personal. but I'm not sure. But anyway, that doesn't matter: *"MOSCOW — Mikhail S. Gorbachev, the Soviet president, won election as a Communist Party deputy to the country's new parliament Wednesday"* http://articles.latimes.com/1989-03-16/news/mn-2159_1_party-members  Gorbachev was not on any ballots, he was one of the party-appointed delegates. The only people who could vote for him were those in the central committee.